# Should TypeScript type aliases always be capitalized?

Tags: typescript

In Codecademy, it seems like they are, but I haven't found anything definite to verify this. And the entry in the TypeScript documentation doesn't specify.

Comment: Typescript doesn't care, so follow the conventions of your project. If you're starting a new project, most Javascript devs use capitalized words for classes, and since type aliases are conceptually similar to classes, I'd say capitalize them too. But the compiler doesn't care in the slightest.

Comment: This is a matter of convention - you don't have to, but it's good to follow convention. The only case where I don't capitalise a type name is in a mapped type like `{[k in K]: ...}` where the keyset is a single-letter type parameter, particularly in contexts where `I`, `J` and `K` in uppercase are already in use.

Answer (score 5):

No - it is simply a convention that some (many) people follow, not something that absolutely *should* or *must* be done.

And note that there are some built-in types that are not capitalized, such as `string`, `number`, `object`, etc.